# How to access written file into /var/test/

Tags: php, linux, unix, permissions, var

If i write a file into /var/test, how can i access it through the website?
Because from having a look at the directories, the file needs to reside in `/var/www/html/` so i can access it through the url.
for example if i were to write into `/var/www/html/directory/file.txt` all i'd need to do to access it is visit the following url:
`www.example.com/directory/file.txt`. But i'm not sure how to do this when writing to `/var/test/file.txt`.
Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access it via the website, unless you configure the server to allow it. Which is a good thing so your web server doesn't expose all of your files to the internet.
See the `Documentroot` and `Alias` Directives in the Web server configuration (assuming you're running apache).

Answer (score 0):

this is a web-server setting, for apache see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html